# How to host multiple sites (running on different ports) on one server through nginx with cloudflare for DNS?

Tags: nginx, dns, digital-ocean, cloudflare, namecheap

I have a DigitalOcean droplet where I'm trying to host multiple servers. To be precise, I have the following setup:
1. My personal site (React frontend hosted using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)) at localhost:5000
2. My Jekyll blog hosted using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) (Command: `bundle exec jeykll serve`) at localhost:4000/blog/
3. A nodejs project hosted using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) at localhost:3031

When I'm test each of them from the server using the above localhost URLs with `curl`, I'm getting the correct response.

I have a domain registered with namecheap, say **abcd.me**, with cloudflare to manage my DNS settings. As given in their instructions, I updated my settings on namecheap to use Cloudflare's nameservers.

What is currently working for me:
- I'm able to access my personal site at https://abcd.me
- I'm able to access my nodejs project at http://{droplet-ip}:3031

What I'm unable to achieve:
- Access my blog at https://blog.abcd.me

Currently, accessing https://blog.abcd.me returns my personal site again, just with the URL prefixed with "blog.". My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {

    listen 3030 default_server;
    listen [::]:3030 default_server;

    server_name {server-ip};

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3031;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name blog.abcd.me www.blog.abcd.me;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/blog/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name abcd.me www.abcd.me;

    # location / {
    #   # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    #   # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #}

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcd.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcd.me/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot




}
```

I'm unable to figure out where I'm going wrong. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You are missing the whole `Listen 443....` part for `server_name blog.abcd.me`

Comment: Ow. That did it for me! I was not fully aware of how to work with ssl certs.Thanks for the help!